# Telefon mask - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript

How to write a telefon mask in Sharepoint +48 xxx-xxx-xxx. 
Does anyone know about it. The telephone mask should be on a field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery

Comment: But how to put the name of the element. How to connect with column ?

Comment: probably something like $("input[Title='Your Phone Field']")